# How to do Flask WTForms form validation when form is partially generated client-side

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm building a simple user interface with two dropdowns. Based on what is selected in the first dropdown, the second dropdown is populated with some new values via jquery/AJAX. The problem is that when the form is submitted, form validation rightly fails because the option in the second dropdown that comes back was not in the list that generated the dropdown in the first place.

I've gotten it to work by injecting whatever data was sent from dropdown 2 into the form object before validating the form. This code is shown below, but it feels like a hacky solution.

```py
form = SearchForm(request.form)

# dropdown 1
form.node_type.choices = [('default', 'Please select a node type')]
form.node_type.choices.extend([(t, t) for t in node_types()])

# dropdown 2
form.node_name.choices = [('default', 'Select a node type first')]

if request.method == 'POST':
    # the below 2 lines are the hack that make it work.
    node_name = request.form.get('node_name')
    form.node_name.choices.append((node_name, node_name))

    if form.validate():
        print('hooray')
```

Is there a standard/recommended way to dynamically add options on the client-side and still have WTForms perform form validation properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pure wtforms solution, but should work with flask-wtf (flask-wtf calls `form.validate()` within `form.validate_on_submit()`).

The code extends `Form.validate` to call a custom validation function if the `node_name` field has failed validation with the 'Not a valid choice' error.  If the validation function returns `True` it removes the 'Not a valid choice' error from `Form.errors` and returns `True` if `Form.errors` is now empty.

```
import werkzeug
import wtforms


class Form(wtforms.Form):

    node_type = wtforms.SelectField(choices=[(x, x) for x in 'ABCDEF'])
    node_name = wtforms.SelectField(choices=[('', '')])

    def validate(self):
        if super().validate():
            return True
        invalid_choice = 'Not a valid choice'
        if 'node_name' in self.errors and invalid_choice in self.errors['node_name']:
            is_valid_node_name = self.cross_validate_node_name()
            if is_valid_node_name:
                self.errors['node_name'].remove(invalid_choice)
                if not self.errors['node_name']:
                    del self.errors['node_name']
                return not self.errors
        return False

    def cross_validate_node_name(self):
        # Implement your validation logic here.
        return self.node_type.data == 'B' and self.node_name.data == 'spam'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    datas = [werkzeug.MultiDict([('node_type', 'A'), ('node_name', 'spam')]),
             werkzeug.MultiDict([('node_type', 'B'), ('node_name', 'spam')])]
    for data in datas:
        form = Form(formdata=data)
        if form.validate():
            print('OK')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
```

Comment: I like this solution because overriding the validate method gives you a reusable chunk of code.